# How to proceed with live, local website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've done plenty of web development at a pretty basic level, and usually just local pages to be called from shared network drives.

Here is where I'm stuck:

I am attempting to build a simple application for work where other leads and I can open a local html page from our shared drive, and add/remove employee names to different tasks, so we can keep tabs on who's doing what.

The tasks are the same every day, just hardcoded titles on sectioned out divs.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to make it to where changes I make will populate for other people with the window open (considering this is just a local page and not a live environment being hosted on anything).

For the general design, I've toyed with hard coding all the employee names under each task in hidden div tags, with a bit of jquery to make the div visible when that worker is assigned.

I have also toyed with appending data to the existing tags using `.innerHTML`.

Still have no idea how to make this live so we can see each others changes.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do it without some sort of shared database. Why not make a Google Doc?

Comment: a wheel is being reinvented

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It may be a bit on the lazy side, but i'm just setting the HTML page to auto refresh every 5s. The data displayed will pull from a notepad doc that leads will be able to update and save.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you just want your peers to be able to see the changes your making live? If so you need to use Ajax. You could set it to ping the server every so often to update on the fly. I'm still quite uncertain as to whether or not that was your question, but if not please elaborate or post your code so I can help further.